# Modify Rack App

Tags: ruby, rubygems, subdomain, rack, middleware

For one of my ruby applications i need the server to route requests based on the subdomain. There are ways to do this using other gems but i decided to make my own "middleware". This code runs applications based on where the request is going to.

config.ru

```
require './subdomain'
require './www'

run Rack::Subdomain.new([
  {
    :subdomain => "test", 
    :application => Sinatra::Application
  }
]);
```

subdomain.rb

```
module Rack
  class Subdomain
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      @app.each do |app|
        match = 'test'.match(app[:subdomain])
        if match
          return app[:application].call(env)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My question is how can i modify this working code to work exactly the same but have it called by code that looks like this:

```
run Rack::Subdomain do
  map 'www' do
    Example::WWW
  end

  map 'api' do
    Example::API
  end
end
```

With suggested code:

config.ru

```
require './subdomain'
require './www'

run Rack::Subdomain.new do |x|
  x.map 'test' do
    Sinatra::Application
  end
end
```

subdomain.rb

```
module Rack
  class Subdomain
    def initialize(routes = nil)
      @routes = routes
      yield self
    end

    def map(subdomain)
      @routes << { subdomain: subdomain, application: yield }
    end

    def call(env)
      @routes.each do |route|
        match = 'test'.match(route[:subdomain])
        if match
          return route[:application].call(env)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You call the above "working code" but it doesn't seem to detect the subdomain at all, but wires it to the literal 'test'.  At any rate, you can implement a pattern similar to what you want by making a map method which adds entries to your list of subdomain->application routes.  I've renamed your `@app` to `@routes` since it is a hash of routes, not an application reference.

```
module Rack
  class Subdomain
    def initialize(routes = [])
      @routes = routes
      yield self if block_given?
    end

    def map(subdomain)
      @routes << { subdomain: subdomain, application: yield }
    end

    def call(env)
      @routes.each do |route|
        match = 'test'.match(route[:subdomain])
        if match
          return route[:application].call(env)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

rsd = Rack::Subdomain.new do |x|
  x.map 'www' do
    Example::WWW
  end

  x.map 'api' do
    Example::API
  end
end

run rsd
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer when testing the above code i got
2013-03-10T19:32:38+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/subdomain.rb:3:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for

Comment: 2013-03-10T19:32:36+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-10T19:32:38+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/subdomain.rb:3:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
2013-03-10T19:32:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2013-03-10T19:32:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1

Comment: I tried to switching around the |x| but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Hi thanks for that but now im getting this error:
"2013-03-11T22:22:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p 59512`
2013-03-11T22:22:46+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/subdomain.rb:5:in `initialize': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)"

Comment: Without seeing your  /app/subdomain.rb it's hard to say what the error is.  Try posting a gist.  Do you have a block attached to the `Rack::Subdomain.new`?  How about to each `x.map` stanza? Have you perhaps used `x.map 'foo' {...}` instead of `x.map 'foo' do...end`

Comment: @CristianRivera Ok, I think the problem is that the block was being passed to `run`, not to `Rack::Subdomain.new` due to operator precedence.  In my example code, I've separated the instantiation of `Rack::Subdomain` from the run to avoid any block binding confusion. I also noticed I was erroneously defaulting routes to nil, instead of an empty array.

Comment: Hi thank you very much it works, i will mark this as the answer, but if you dont mind i am wondering about one more thing, is there any way we can make this code not have to use the x.map and use just map and also does the run have to be at the bottom?

Comment: you can avoid the `x.map` by doing an `self.instance_eval` on the block instead of a simple `yield self`, but I don't advise that.  By doing `instance_eval` you change the default receiver `self` for the block's execution which changes the method dispatch and instance variables that might be referenced in the block in unintuitive ways.

Comment: Ok thank you for that advice. Is there any way to do it the way Rack URL map does it? Like: run Rack::URLMap.new([
  "/" => my_app, "test" => my_other_app])