# Undefined method `to_i' for Hash

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rack

I am trying to make a subdomain router for my Rack app but I ran into a problem. Here is my config.ru code:

```
require './controllers/subdomain'
require './controllers/www'

set :root, './'

run Example::Subdomain.new({
                                :www => Sinatra::Application
                            })
```

and here is my subdomain.rb code:

```
module Example
  class Subdomain
    def initialize(map = {})
      @map = map
    end

    def call(env)
      @map.each do |subdomain, app|
        if env['HTTP_HOST'].split('.').first.eql?(subdomain)
          app.call(env)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for {:www=>Sinatra::Application}:Hash
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:555:in `check_status'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:19:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:19:in `assert'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:555:in `check_status'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:51:in `_call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call_without_check'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:161:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/chunked.rb:43:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `pre_process'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4
  /usr/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
  /usr/bin/rackup:19
  -e:1:in `load'
  -e:1
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening instead of running the `app.call(env)`?

This is a screenshot of the error:
http://i46.tinypic.com/3538is6.jpg

Also this code works, but it doesn't abide by the subdomain rule tho:

```
module Example
  class Subdomain
    def initialize(map = {})
      @map = map
    end

    def call(env)
      @map.each do |subdomain, app|
        return app.call(env)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I also tested the subdomain code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325002/modify-rack-app and i still get the same error so i don't think its my code it has to be something with the rack status code but i cant figure out where the problem is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this with the following code:

```
module Example
  class Subdomain
    def initialize(map = {})
      @map = map
    end

    def call(env)
      @map.each { |subdomain, app| return app.call(env) if env['HTTP_HOST'].split('.').first.eql?(subdomain) }
    end
  end
end

run Example::Subdomain.new({
        'www' => Sinatra::Application,
        'api' => Example::API
    })
```

I changed the hash values to strings encased in '' and added a `return` to the `app.call(env)`

Answer (score 2):

Rack thinks you are returning the `@map` for the status code in the triplet of the response which is `[status, headers, body]` (as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_%28web_server_interface%29)). This is because `each` returns the collection at the end of its iteration, and this is being used as the return value of your `call`.

Perhaps this will work for you, or at least get you started:

```
def call(env)
  subdomain = env['HTTP_HOST'].split('.').first
  app = @map[subdomain]
  app.call(env)
end
```